# Angular SCSS styling issue

Tags: html, angular

So basically I am trying to get my header to reach the full width of the page but it isn't. There is a white bar remaining on each end of the header which isn't working I tried resetting the default browser settings but doesn't seem to work. I am aswell just learning Angular now.

SCSS Code:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coda');

body {
  padding: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(black,blue);

  .headerTitle {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Coda', cursive;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try replicating your issue on stackblitz if possible, it could be something to do with the margins and paddings you're setting on the body, but if we can't see the issue its hard to help you

Comment: Why is `margin: 0 auto;padding: 0 auto;` on your body?

Answer (score 0):

you need to put .header in the css

```
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coda');
body {
  padding: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(black,blue);
  .headerTitle{
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Coda', cursive;
  }
}
```

Comment: As much as we know, `header` can also be a tag selector and not a typo